# Can't understand the logical structure of Euclid's infinitely many primes proof in Rosen's book.

Tags: proof-verification, logic, prime-numbers, proof-explanation

I'm reading the book *Discrete Mathematics and It's Applications* written by Rosen. At page 260, there is a proof using the technique similar to Euclid's. The following is my trying to understand the proof.

---

Assume that there are only finitely many primes, $p_1, p_2, ..., p_n$, I'll call it prime list later on. Let

$$Q = p_1p_2\cdots p_n+1.$$

By the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, $Q$ is prime or else it can be written as the product of two or more primes.

Let $p_j$ be an arbitrary prime in the prime list. Then $p_j$ can't divide $Q$, since:

1. If $p_j \mid Q$, then $p_j \mid (Q - p_1p_2\cdots p_n=1)$:

   The is because $p_j \mid (p_1p_2\cdots p_n)$, so $p_j \mid (1\cdot Q+(-1)\cdot(p_1p_2\cdots p_n))$.
2. Since $p_j \mid (Q - p_1p_2\cdots p_n=1)$ is false, $p_j \not\mid Q$:

   The only integer which divides all integer is $1$, but $p_j$ is a prime.

Since $p_j \not\mid Q$ also means that $Q$ is not $p_j$, $Q$ is not in the prime list. And since there is no prime in the prime list divides $Q$, $Q$ can't be written as the product of two or more primes. Finally, $Q$ has to be a prime, which is not in the prime list. We've arrived a contradiction.

---

I'm not sure whether it's correct, but that's how I understand the proof. And the following is the proof in my book:

[image]
[image]

I don't understand why it arrives the conclusion "*Hence, there is a prime not in the list*".

Please give me some hints...

Comment: Either $Q$ is prime or not. If it is prime, it is not in the "primes list" because it is greater than every prime in the list. Thus, $Q$ is **not** prime and hence must have a prime factor: but **all** primes are in the list (by assumption) and thus some of them must divide $Q$.

Comment: To @MauroALLEGRANZA: But how did you know it's greater than every prime in the list?

Comment: Because is the product of them all plus 1 !

Comment: To @MauroALLEGRANZA: I totally agree with you. Sorry if I made you angry. And apparently, by my intuition that's absolutely true. But when I writing a proof, it's just a little "uneasy" to directly say something is greater than something else, by eyes.

Comment: Ugh. This book proof is everything I hate about logic introductions. 1) The Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic is overkill. 2) This isn't a proof by contradiction but a proof of the negation: "the set of primes is not finite". 3) We could view this as a proof by contradiction of "you aren't unable to extend any finite list of primes", but it actually *constructively* proves the direct statement, perhaps worded "the set of all primes is more numerous than any assigned multitude of primes", so a proof by contradiction is silly. 4) As you probably guessed, the quoted statement is from Elements.

Comment: To @DerekElkins: I'm very interested in what you said. I agree with your 1), 3), still not clear for me about your 2), and it's also not clear that you meant the quoted statement in your comment or in my question. If you could organize it into answer, I'll appreciate it.

Comment: To @DerekElkins: Ok, I guess I know your 3), this is my try: We don't have to even assume that there are *finitely* many primes. Just prove that "Given a set of finitely many primes, we can generate a prime which is not in the set.". So even a proof by contradiction will be a overkill. I've fixed the typo...

Comment: By "quoted statement" I was referring to "the set of all primes is more numerous than any assigned multitude of primes" which is a slight rewording of Proposition 20 of Book IX as [translated by Fitzpatrick](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/Books/Euclid/Elements.pdf). The phrase "proof by contradiction" is often used to ambiguously refer to [two superficially similar inference rules](http://math.andrej.com/2010/03/29/proof-of-negation-and-proof-by-contradiction/) that are deeply dissimilar. It's possible the book consistently uses it for negation introduction, but I doubt that.

Comment: If the theorem is "there are infinitely many primes" and the definition of "infinitely many" is "not finitely many", then the appropriate logical structure is a negation introduction which does take the form of "assume there are finitely many and derive a contradiction". As the link in the previous comment describes, this is distinct from a rule that is often called "proof by contradiction". "Given a set of finitely many primes, we can generate a prime which is not in the set" is a different, stronger theorem unless we take this as the definition of "infinitely many".

Comment: To @DerekElkins: I respect every words you've said but why not organize them into an answer? So it will be more easily seen by all others.

Comment: @DerekElkins: lol, I actually wanted to say "we can generate a number consists of a prime which is not in the list", not generate prime, sorry...

Comment: As far as I can tell, your issues with the given proof have to do with number-theoretic concerns which is consistent with the focus of all the answers. My comment does not address those issues which is why I didn't make it an answer. The motivation for my comment is annoyance (directed at the book) with the (very probable) confusion about "proof by contradiction" it is sowing and the subtle misrepresentation of classical (as in old) theorems and proofs.

Comment: We actually do not need the fundamental theorem of number theory. We just need the following argument : If $n>1$ is an integer, the set of divisors $t>1$ of $n$ is not empty because $n$ is in the set. The smallest element in the set must be a prime number (otherwise we could find a smaller divisor still greater than $1$). This shows that every integer greater than $1$ is divisible by a prime. With this, Euklids proof becomes utterly trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement "$Q$ is prime or else it can be written as a product of two or more primes" implies there exists a prime dividing $Q$. Since none of the $p_j$ have this property, there has to be another prime not in the list which divides $Q$.

Answer (score 2):

If $p$ is a prime number such that $p\mid Q$ then, since $Q-p_1p_2\ldots p_n=1$, $p\notin\{p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_n\}$ because otherwise $p\mid1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p_j$ be a prime dividing $Q=p_1p_2\ldots p_n+1$. If $p_j$ is a prime in the list $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_n$, then $p_j\mid Q-1$.

This means that there is some integer $k$ such that $Q=p_jk$ and some other integer $m$ such that $Q-1=p_jm$. Subtracting these two gives:
$$1=Q-(Q-1)=p_j(k-m)$$
So $p_j$ divides $1$, but $p_j>1$, which is impossible

Answer (score -4):

I was going through checking it by arbitrary number.
 Let's  $Q= 9699691$ be the  prime number because as stated above   none of $p_j$ (i.e $2$ to $19$ prime numbers) divides $Q$ which can be represented as 
$Q= 2\times3\times5\times7\times11\times13\times17\times19+1$ which must be prime number.
But $Q = 9699691=347\times27953$ which is a composite number. 
The thing is that the statement "$Q$ is prime or else it can be written as a product of two or more primes" implies there exists a prime dividing $Q$ but it ain't at our list. Since none of the $p_j$ have this property, there has to be another prime not in the list which divides $Q$.. which is why 
 $347$, $27953$ does... both are primes.

Hope, this clarifies everything.